# Oracle Error Inconsistent Datatype on select statement

Tags: oracle, select, types

I'm using the Oracle's console *Database Express Edition* and I'm creating a database with my own data types. Everything is OK creating and inserting new data, but when I make a select from my data type, for example, "direccion", Oracle returns me the error 00932, "inconsistent datatypes".

I execute this code:

```
CREATE TYPE lista_tel_t AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(20) ; 

CREATE TYPE direccion_t AS OBJECT (
    calle VARCHAR2(200),
    ciudad VARCHAR2(200),
    prov CHAR(2),
    codpos VARCHAR2(20)
) ;

CREATE TYPE cliente_t AS OBJECT (
    clinum NUMBER,
    clinomb VARCHAR2(200), 
    direccion direccion_t,
    lista_tel lista_tel_t
) ;

CREATE TABLE cliente_tab OF cliente_t(clinum PRIMARY KEY);
```

The problem comes when I make a select from a type, for example:

```
SELECT direccion FROM cliente_tab;
```

When I make this select it returns me the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DIRECCION_T
```

My question is... **How can I make the select and show the result properly?**

Comment: Based on your code, the `ORA-00932` should not be raised. Try to execute that `select` statement in SQL*PLUS or SQL Developer or any other client instead of  Oracle XE graphical console.

Comment: can you show some sample data

Comment: Just to underline @NicholasKrasnov your code runs in SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0039fe/1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT direccion.calle,
       direccion.ciudad,
       direccion.prov,
       direccion.codpos
  FROM cliente_tab;
```

Or, if you want to work in PL/SQL with objects you may try to Bulk Collect the table into a collection of objects.

For more information see the [*Oracle® Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm)